# php: cli shell_exec vs web shell_exec

Tags: php, linux, bash, pdf, pandoc

I'm dealing with this problem all the day, I would like to generate a document with pandoc in the background:

I have this sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp=$1
pdf=$2
/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/pandoc $tmp -f markdown -t latex --pdf-engine=xelatex -o $pdf 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I have this php: pandoc.php

```
<?php
$command = "/bin/bash /home/projects/sarebide/generate_pdf.sh /home/projects/sarebide/tmp/1607456639 /home/projects/sarebide/certified/extract_1.pdf"
shell_exec($command);
```

In shell works fine:

```
/bin/bash /home/projects/sarebide/generate_pdf.sh /home/projects/sarebide/tmp/1607456639 /home/projects/sarebide/certified/extract_1.pdf
```

ps result:

```
ps aux | grep pandoc
pi        9004 51.0  6.2 170184 59232 pts/2    Sl   20:46   0:01 /usr/bin/pandoc /home/projects/sarebide/tmp/1607456639 -f markdown -t latex --pdf-engine=xelatex -o /home/projects/sarebide/certified/extract_1.pdf
pi        9012  0.0  0.0   7348   540 pts/2    S+   20:47   0:00 grep --color=auto pandoc
```

In the shell running with php works fine:

```
php pandoc.php
```

ps result:

```
ps aux | grep pandoc
pi        9382  133  6.1 170184 58268 pts/2    Rl   21:05   0:01 /usr/bin/pandoc /home/projects/sarebide/tmp/1607456639 -f markdown -t latex --pdf-engine=xelatex -o /home/projects/sarebide/certified/extract_1.pdf
pi        8983  0.0  0.0   7348   528 pts/2    S+   20:46   0:00 grep --color=auto pandoc
```

But when I execute it throught web: **http://localhost/pandoc.php**

ps result:

```
ps aux | grep pandoc
pi        8983  0.0  0.0   7348   528 pts/2    S+   20:46   0:00 grep --color=auto pandoc
```

the shell_exec result is **NULL**

the user for shell and web is the same: **pi**, the result of whoami in the shell and in the web is the same.

Some others commands with shell_exec fors fine.

Am I missing something? Thank you!

Comment: I bet the command is trying to tell you what's wrong, but you added `1>/dev/null 2>&1` to suppress all helpful error messages

Comment: @thatotherguy if i remove this message appears `/usr/bin/nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout`

Comment: Things you might try or check: (1.) is the script/pandoc allowed to create temporary files (required for PDF compilation) (2.) can you convert to other formats, e.g., docx? (3.) could there be a space in the path? Variables should be surrounded by double quotes to avoid problems. E.g. `tmp="$1"` (4.) Run pandoc with `--verbose` and log output with `--log=FILE`.

Comment: @tarleb I will try it, thank you